# Passing an array to a function does not work

Tags: shell, sh

I am trying to pass an array to another function.

I have a function:

```
function2(){
   echo "function2 called"

}
```

and the calling function

```
function1(){

          timeStamp="201912134349"
          TMP_STORAGE_LOAD_COPY="/load/copy/NODE00"
          NUM_OF_MLN=`wc -l /head/home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2nodes.cfg | awk '{print $1}'`
          for (( idx=0; idx<$NUM_OF_MLN; idx++ ))
          do
              local_backup_directory=$TMP_STORAGE_LOAD_COPY"0$idx"
              tarScratchFileName[idx]="scratch_backup_${idx}.$timeStamp.tgz"
              local tarFileLocalScratchPath[idx]="$local_backup_directory/${tarScratchFileName[idx]}"
              echo "tarScratchFileName: ${tarFileLocalScratchPath[idx]}"
              local objectStoreScratchBackupPath[idx]="$OBJECTSTORE_BACKUP_PATH/${tarScratchFileName[idx]}"
          done
         echo "calling . $SCRIPT_DIR/include/cloud_bar.sh; function2 $timeStamp  ${tarFileLocalScratchPath[@]}"
         ssh_parallel ". $SCRIPT_DIR/include/cloud_bar.sh; function2 $timeStamp ${tarFileLocalScratchPath[@]}"
}
```

When I call function1 I get the following o/p:

```
calling . /opt/ibm/dashdb-scripts/recovery/include/cloud_bar.sh; function2 20190722190241 /local/db2inst1/NODE0000/scratch_backup_0.20190722190241.tgz /local/db2inst1/NODE0001/scratch_backup_1.20190722190241.tgz /local/db2inst1/NODE0002/scratch_backup_2.20190722190241.tgz /local/db2inst1/NODE0003/scratch_backup_3.20190722190241.tgz /local/db2inst1/NODE0004/scratch_backup_4.20190722190241.tgz /local/db2inst1/NODE0005/scratch_backup_5.20190722190241.tgz /local/db2inst1/NODE0006/scratch_backup_6.20190722190241.tgz /local/db2inst1/NODE0007/scratch_backup_7.20190722190241.tgz
```

So the list is getting passed properly. But the function2 never gets called. I can't see `function2 called`. Earlier I was passing a single string and the function was getting called properly but with a list it doesn't.

Comment: `sh` doesn't have arrays.  Which array supporting variant of sh are you using?

Comment: What is `ssh_parallel` here?

Comment: Ignore ssh_parallel that's a utility we have for running the script on all the nodes parallely. Updated question with how I am creating a list/array. Can it be not passed to another function at all?

Comment: The values that the array syntax *expand* to can be passed like any other arguments, but that's irrelevant if `function2` isn't being called in the first place, a situation in which the definition of `ssh_parallel` seems *very* relevant.

Comment: Right now, you just have a call to `ssh_parallel` which takes a *string* containing what looks like a shell command as its argument. How or if that command gets executed depends entirely on what `ssh_parallel` is doing. Assuming it does what I suspect it does, where does `function2` get defined on the *remote* hosts?

Comment: @aaj : Aside from the correct comment by WilliamPursell : Even in bash, ksh and zsh, you can not pass an array as a single parameter to a function.